# Write Face Tags to XMP files (not embedded) as well as XMP metadata embedded in JPG

Tags: python, metadata, exif, face, xmp

I have Face Tags data (Name of persons and X/Y and size of each boxes for each image) in my database.

I want to update the corresponding JPEG or XMP files with this information.

I'm aware about ExifTool but I dont see how to create this kind of list for each image.

I may use python or cmd prompt logic for that.

Note: I tried [How to write WIC XMP people tags to jpg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62123458/how-to-write-wic-xmp-people-tags-to-jpg)
Exiftools update the file, but the box/name wont show on any software (Photo,Lightroom,XnView) , even if I add keyword person as tag as well, the name appear in Explorer on People tab though.

Comment: That link gives info on how to write the [Microsoft Regions Struct](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Microsoft.html#Regions), which isn't really used by anything outside of the old MS Live Photo Gallery.  What you want to do is write is the [MWG Regions Tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/MWG.html#Regions).

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment I did the following cmd line that solve it:

```
exiftool -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionAppliedToDimensionsH=4000 -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionAppliedToDimensionsUnit="pixel" -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionAppliedToDimensionsW=6000 -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionAreaX=0.319270833 -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionAreaY=0.21015625 -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionAreaW=0.165104167 -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionAreaH=0.30390625 -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionName=John -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionRotation=0 -xmp-mwg-rs:RegionType="Face" myfile.xmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using structured tags instead of many flat tags. (https://exiftool.org/struct.html)

This way you can set many regions for each image.

exiftool "-RegionInfo<=file" ./img.jpg

file:

```
{
    AppliedToDimensions =
    {
        W = 4000,
        H = 3000,
        Unit = pixel,
    },
    RegionList =
    [
        {
            Area =
            {
                W = 0.13375, H = 0.178333333, X = 0.19, Y = 0.075,
                Unit = normalized,
            },
            Name = Person 1,
            Type = Face,
        },
        {
            Area =
            {
                W = 0.13375, H = 0.178333333, X = 0.9775, Y = 0.114666667,
                Unit = normalized,
            },
            Name = Person 2,
            Type = Face,
        },
        {
            Area =
            {
                W = 0.13375, H = 0.178333333, X = 0.9775, Y = 0.808,
                Unit = normalized,
            },
            Name = Person 3,
            Type = Face,
        },
        {
            Area =
            {
                W = 0.13375, H = 0.178333333, X = 0.146, Y = 0.822,
                Unit = normalized,
            },
            Name = Person 4
            Type = Face,
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).